# Why is a Boolean output not given as True/False by SystemModelSimulate?

Tags: bugs, system-modeler, system-modeling

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in 12.1**

---

I am a bit surprised that I am not getting a *boolean* output for the following simple Modelica model:

```
model = ImportString[
    "block Or
        input Boolean u1;
        input Boolean u2;
        output Boolean y;
     equation
        y = (u1 or u2);
     end Or;"
   ,
   "Mo"
];

sim = SystemModelSimulate[ model, {"y"}, {0,1},
    Association[
        "Inputs" -> {
            "u1" -> Function[ t, True ],
            "u2" -> Function[ t, False ]
        }
    ]
];

First @ sim[{"y"}]
```

> Function[ t, 1., Listable ]

So, what is returned is the real output (e.g. `Boole[y]`). Is this a bug?

Comment: I (as a developer working on system modeling in Wolfram Language) consider it at least an unfortunate behavior. I have reported it in our issue tracker internally.

Comment: @Malte Great to hear. It indeed makes wiritng `VerificationTest` in a test notebook (a great feature btw) a bit more opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Malte Lenz and now officially Wolfram Support have confirmed, **this is a bug**.

Note, that not only will **Boolean outputs** be given *numerically*  by `SystemModelSimulate`, but **Boolean inputs** also have to be given as `1` or `0` instead of `True` or `False`.